# To create a hyperledger fabric app with multiple organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was using Hyperledger fabric for creating blockchain network. I tried out the tutorial with a single peer, single orderer etc. It worked fine. But I need to build a network like this: [image]

i.e with multiple organization. At least 2 organizations. How do I need to specify the crypto-config.yaml, configtx.yaml etc.
Right now I used like this:

crypto-config.yaml

```
    OrdererOrgs:
      - Name: Orderer1
        Domain: healthcare1.com
        Specs:
          - Hostname: orderer1
      - Name: Orderer2
        Domain: healthcare2.com
        Specs:
          - Hostname: orderer2
```

configtx.yaml

Profiles:

```
TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Orderer1
            - *Orderer2
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Hospital1
                - *Hospital2
TwoOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Hospital1
            - *Hospital2
Organizations:
# SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
# in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
- &Orderer1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Orderer1

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Orderer1MSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/healthcare1.com/msp

- &Orderer2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Orderer2

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Orderer2MSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/healthcare2.com/msp

- &Hospital1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Hospital1MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Hospital1MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital1.healthcare1.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.hospital1.healthcare1.com
          Port: 7051

- &Hospital2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Hospital2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Hospital2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital2.healthcare2.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.hospital2.healthcare2.com
              Port: 7051
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
# Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
# Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
OrdererType: solo

Addresses:
    - orderer1.healthcare1.com:7050
    - orderer2.healthcare2.com:7050

# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
BatchTimeout: 2s

# Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
BatchSize:

    # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
    MaxMessageCount: 10

    # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch.
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

    # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
    # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

Kafka:
    # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
    # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
    Brokers:
        - 127.0.0.1:9092

# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the orderer side of the network
Organizations:
```

But I am stuck at docker-compose.yaml file. I also need to know am I going the right way or is there any mistakes in the above files also.

Any other links other than the official documentation are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to setup this network? How did you configure organization to have an orderer node as well?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not currently possible to distribute orderers across multiple organisations. At least not using the `solo` orderer, which needs to be a single orderer node; nor the `kafka` orderer system, which depends on a single Kafka cluster.

Multi-organisation ordering will probably need to wait until a BFT ordering solution is available.

Comment: you mean an organization having 'n' peers can't participate in ordering? Ordering must be provided by some third organization? I want an organization to have an orderer node as well along with peers, is it possible? Thanks

Comment: You can use BFT SMaRt if you want to distribute orderers and ignore Kafka, but it's an "add-on" and I have not used it myself.

https://github.com/bft-smart/fabric-orderingservice

Comment: But you can have an organisation that has both peers and orderers, but the orderers need to be localised to a single organisation AFAIK (without BFT SMaRt)